# Find and replace occurrence of string in whole html itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Assume

```
<html>  
<head>....</head>
<body>
 .
 .  // Occurrences are here
 .  
</body>
</html>
```

I do

```
$(function()
{
    $('html').html() = $('html').html().replace(/strToFind/g,'somethingElse');
});
```

in head, but it does't work. How I do to find and replace all occurrence of string in html document itself (not store in variable)?
Thanks

Comment: This problem is pretty obvious but in future you should really describe the problem further than "it doesn't work".. How does it not work, does the console say anything, etc...

Comment: Be aware that replacing the whole HTML can break the functionality of the site because you are destroying all existing DOM elements. All already bound event handlers will be gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.html()` is a function that returns the HTML, you can't assign to it. If you want to change the HTML of an object in jQuery, you put the new HTML as a parameter to the function:

```
$('html').html($('html').html().replace(/strToFind/g,'somethingElse'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('html').html()` would return the html string , but won't set it.

You can use this function

```
function rep_all()
{
    var str = $('html').html();
    str.replace('strtofind','strtoreplace');
    $('html').html(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` is something which writes on the html page it is not like variable so you can't assign anythig to it. you need to put the value inside it.like this:

```
$('html').html( $('html').html().replace(/strToFind/g,'somethingElse'));
```

see here:http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

It's been answered that the `.html()` is not assignable, you would have to pass the replaced content as a parameter.

Just to point out, it is ***very*** uncommon to replace the whole page's `html` content.

As you defined that the contents to be replaced are inside the `body`, you should at least (still not good) target only the `body`:

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/strToFind/g,'somethingElse'))
```